# Explain to me this solved part of exercise please?

Tags: operational-amplifier

We have the exercise :

The figure shows an op amp connected in the noninverting configuration. The op amp has an openloop gain μ, a differential input resistance Rid, and an output resistance ro. Recall that in our analysis of op-amp circuits in Chapter 2, we neglected the effects of Rid (assumed it to be infinite) and of ro (assumed it to be zero). Here we wish to use the feedback method to analyze the circuit taking both Rid and ro into
account. Find expressions for A, β, the closed-loop gain , the input resistance Rin and the output resistance Rout. Also find numerical values, given μ = 104, Rid = 100 kΩ, ro = 1 kΩ, RL = 2 kΩ, R1 = 1 kΩ, R2 = 1 MΩ, and Rs = 10 kΩ.

Now,this exercise is already solved in the book.Here it is 
[image]
Here is the second figure [image]

**My question is** : We know that Rs=10 KOhm.Rif=777 KOhm. Now,Rin=Rif-Rs=777-10=767 KOhm.As I have underlined in the second picture,why is Rin=739 kohm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it must be a typo. Using a completely different approach, I came up with a value for R<sub>in</sub> of 766K.

Assuming µ is really 10<sup>4</sup> (not 104), I solved for the voltage at the inverting input of the opamp as a function of V<sub>1</sub>, and came up with V<sub>-</sub> = V<sub>1</sub> × 6.6555. This means that the effective resistance between the inverting input and ground (the *real* value of R<sub>11</sub>) must be 6.6555 × R<sub>id</sub>, or 665.55 kΩ. R<sub>in</sub> is the sum of these two resistances, or 765.55 kΩ.

Comment: Yes - I arrived at the same value: Rin=766 kohms.